# Rails local variable order in erb causing errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, formbuilder

So I have the following erb that works:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <%- @user_skills.each do |user_skill| %>
    <li class="list-group-item"><%= user_skill.skill.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= semantic_form_for current_user.user_skills.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs %>
  <%= f.actions  %>
<% end %>
```

In my controller, I have a `@user_skills = current_user.user_skills`.
Once I swap the two blocks:

```
<%= semantic_form_for current_user.user_skills.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs %>
  <%= f.actions  %>
<% end %>

<ul class="list-group">
  <%- @user_skills.each do |user_skill| %>
    <li class="list-group-item"><%= user_skill.skill.name %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

It raises an error like this: `undefined method`name' for nil:NilClass`. So I'm guessing the form builder is somehow overwriting the user_skill inside the ul block. But why and how do I resolve the problem? It doesn't seem to be a formtastic issue, since I also used the native form builder.

UPDATE: 
So I found out that the @user_skills array actually contains the just created user_skill, which hasn't been persisted and do not have a `#skill_id` or `#skill.name`! And if I do `UserSkill.new` at the start of the form, then the @user_skills array will be ok. Maybe there is a caching layer in activerecord that will automatically include just created objects into the query. Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `current_user.user_skills.new` adds a blank `user_skill` to the `has_many` association of `current_user`. Since `@user_skills` is simply a reference to `current_user.user_skills`, the blank instance is included in the the unordered list when iterating after initializing the new user_skill record.

You'd be better off simply initializing a new `user_skill` in the form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for UserSkill.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs %>
  <%= f.actions  %>
<% end %>
```

Then, in the create action of your `UserSkillsController`, associate the `user_skill` attributes with the `current_user`. A bare-bones version could look something like:

```
def create
  @user_skill = current_user.user_skills.create(params[:user_skill])
  respond_with @user_skill
end
```

Comment: Thanks. That's also what I found out as well. I assumed the current_user.user_skills will only include persisted objects, which obviously is not true.